# IN clause not working in WHERE condition in MYSQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am creating a trigger that have a MYSQL query having IN clause look like below.

```
drop trigger onPublish;
delimiter $$
create trigger onPublish AFTER insert on publish_drawing_details
for each row
begin
Declare userIds VARCHAR(255);
set userIds = (select GROUP_CONCAT(refUser) from manpower where refProject=new.refProjectId and refRoleType in (select role from hr_user));
insert into notification_container(loginUserId,mailSubject,projectId,userIds,attachmentIds,ccMails,mailText,metaNotificationEventId)
values (new.submittedBy,new.mailSubject,new.refProjectId,userIds,new.attachmentIds,new.ccEmails,new.mailText,1);
end $$
```

It works fine if I write this like `set userIds = (select GROUP_CONCAT(refUser) from manpower where refProject=new.refProjectId and refRoleType in (1,2,3,4,5));`

I try it like `set userIds = (select GROUP_CONCAT(refUser) from manpower where refProject=new.refProjectId and refRoleType in (select GROUP_CONCAT(role) from hr_user));`

but don't work at all.

Comment: Please format the code in your post such that we can read it.

Comment: You are going to insert serialized keys. That's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `GROUP_CONCAT` in inner query, try the following:

```
SET userIds = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(refUser) 
    FROM manpower 
    WHERE refProject=new.refProjectId 
    AND refRoleType IN (
        SELECT role 
        FROM hr_user
    )
);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. It throw an error `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,2,3,4,5'`. Here 1,2,3,4,5 is result of inner query. I know it work in query browser but not work in trigger

Comment: Here `role` is comma separated id's column